# Bootstrap button dropdown in asp.net button

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, twitter-bootstrap

I wanted to implement Bootstrap dropdown button in asp.net button

Here is Bootstrap Button

```html
<!-- Split button -->
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Action</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <span class="caret"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Here i implement upto button but i don't know how to do the dropdown part

```
<asp:Button ID="btnMore" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" 
    data-toggle="dropdown" runat="server" Text="SMS" />
```

You can see this button in bootstrap [Click Here](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-dropdowns)

Comment: An easier way would be to add `runat="server"` and use `OnServerClick=""` with your existing html above.

Comment: Are you loading bootstrap.min.js and bootstrap.dropdown.js both?

Comment: @mxmissile I use that but how to implement Dropdown

Comment: @Dnyanesh Yes load both.

Comment: Then do not load bootstrap.dropdown.js and code should work for you.

Comment: When you realize that this "kind" of button has actions associated with it, you "know" that the normal asp.net button won't do. You have to create a custom server control. There are many github/codeplex solutions you can look at...check out: https://bootstrapcontrols.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

Two points you need to change.
The button `action` that make the post back and call your function on code behind and the link on the menu to do the same.

You only need to add the correct `CssClass` on the asp.net button for the first.
For the menu links you can use the `LinkButton` asp.net control with out any other settings (css style I mean)

And here is a working tested example:

```
<!-- Split button -->
<div class="btn-group">
  <!-- here is the asp.net button to make post back -->
  <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Action" CssClass="btn btn-danger" />      
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <span class="caret"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <!-- here is the asp.net link button to make post back -->
    <li><asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server">Action</asp:LinkButton></li>        
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The second button that opens the menu is not need to be asp.net control, is just opens the menu, is not call any code behind function. So you left it as is.